# How to do an HTTP GET and POST from one API to another endpoint from scratch

Tags: java, visual-studio, http, netbeans

So I'm completely NEW to the HTTP request thing, and here's the case:

1. I received an API key.
2. I need to use an HTTP GET to receive code from one API endpoint, using the given key.
3. Do some changes.
4. And POST to another API endpoint.

Any language and coding environment is allowed to accomplish this, but the problem is, I don't even know what software I should use, what language I can use, and how to set up the coding environment.

So can anyone please give a detailed explanation for the steps I should do?
Including the coding environment (Could I use Visual studio? Or easier with Netbeans?), language I should use (Java first), and the example code for how to use HTTP GET, to get data from an API endpoint using an existing API key.

The important thing is that I know what steps I need to do, but I COMPLETELY don't know how I should do this.

Comment: Have you tried PHP before?

Comment: This can be accomplished in any general-purpose programming language. Pick one.

Comment: _"The important thing is I know what steps I need to do but I COMPLETELY don't know how should I do"_ - sorry, but that is not a question suitable for this site, because it is just too broad. We're here to help with _specific_ problems that you face while coding - but not to start at the very basics.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Following @CBroe's comment... Your question is likely to be down-voted, as it is off-topic. It is too broad in nature, for which answers would be too large, or opinionated. You need to show your own effort and attempts at researching the problem, and then ask a specific question about a _specific_ issue you've come across and need help solving. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.